# The images are not displayed to disable AdRotate

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a WordPress (v. 4.5.3) operating with various plugins. I want to stop using the AdRotate (v. 3.15.5.2) plugin but when you disable or remove, stop showing images on every page (the space is respected but not shown) except the logo.

If I check the console with F12, shows no errors, and if I go to the network tab, the images load perfectly.
How I can remove the plugin without affecting images? The theme is Newspaper.

Comment: Can you please share the link of your front page. and also deactivate that plugin. so i can check what is the problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution. The problem is a bug in the theme Newspaper 6 with AdRotate plugin, upgrading to Newspaper 7 the error is resolved.